# Android set AlarmManager to Show Notification for specific Date and time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my application I would like to set an AlarmManager to a specific time: `2016-11-15 13:00:00`. Then show a notification (or toast) without repeating it and then turn off. But my code doesn't work.

**MainActivity**:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.clear();
    cal.set(2016, 11, 15, 13, 00);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**AlarmReceiver**:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Utils.toast("dddddd", context);
        Log.e("alarm!!!!!! ", " fire");
    }
}
```

**manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<receiver android:name=".Views.AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

What is the problem with this code, why does the `alarm manager` not show a `toast` or `Log`?

Comment: Os Version of the device which you are testing?

Comment: Your alarm receiver works for only two actions (you have set them in intent filter). Apart from that on which api level you are testing?

Comment: @MujammilAhamed my android version is `6.0.1`

Comment: @mallaudin your mean is android version?

Comment: Keep in mind that `AlarmManager#set()` is inexact since KitKat if your `targetSdkVersion` >= 19, so it might be slightly off of the exact time set.

Comment: Whoops. I just realized I didn't copy the link I thought I did, but that one still shows the problem. Your month is off by one.

Comment: @MikeM. problem resolved by minus month, Thanks